# Chapter names character problem

Tags: languages

[image]

my main.tex file and chapter1.tex files are given above. When i use Turkish characters in the chapter names, chapter names does not appear correctly in the thesis.

How can i fix this problem? Thank you.

chapter1.tex is:

```
\chapter{GİRİŞ ÖÇĞÜ öçişüğ}
text
```

main.tex is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%Türkçe heceleme
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%Türkçe karakterler
\usepackage[turkish,english,shorthands=:!]{babel}%Türkçe bölüm isimleri
\usepackage{apacite}
%%% left: 30mm, top: 30mm, right: 25mm, bottom: 25mm
\usepackage[a4paper,left=30mm,top=30mm,right=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize,bf}]{caption}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize,bf}]{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{tikz}             
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}    

%%% For dummy texts, you can remove it.
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%% Turning off all figures, required for turnitin upload to reduce the size of the document.
%%% Remove the next two lines if you want the figures at their place
%\usepackage[figuresonly,nolists,nomarkers]{endfloat}
%\renewcommand{\processdelayedfloats}{}

%%% Same fonts for URL
\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}}

%%% Figure and Table counters
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}


\selectlanguage{turkish}

%****************************************
% SPACING

%%% Footnote line spacing
\setlength{\footnotesep}{\baselineskip}

%%% Adding extra space between paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
%........................................


%****************************************
% BIBLIOGRAPHY

%%% Bibliography line spacing
\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}

%%% Removing parentheses around year in bibliography
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand{\BBOP}{}
\renewcommand{\BBCP}{}
}

%%% Adding ":" character before page number in citations
\bibpunct[: ]{(}{)}{:}{a}{,}{~}
%........................................


%****************************************
% BLOCK QUOTES

%%% Spaces before and after block quotes
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
\AtEndEnvironment{quote}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}

%%% Spaces before and after block quotes, indentation
\renewcommand{\quote}{\list{}{\rightmargin=4em\leftmargin=4em}\item\relax}

%%% Spacing
\expandafter\def\expandafter\quote\expandafter{\quote\singlespacing}
%........................................


%****************************************
% CHAPTERS

%%% Chapter titles
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
        {\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\centering\bfseries}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\  \thechapter}{2\baselineskip}{\uppercase}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}}

%%% Chapter title spacing
%%% Centered, Top: 50mm, Next: 3 line after
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{13mm}{3\baselineskip} 

%%% Bibliography title spacing
%%% Centered, Top: 50mm, Next: 4 line after
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{16mm}{4\baselineskip} 

%%% RENAMING CHAPTER TITLES
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase{Table of Contents}}%
  \renewcommand{\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase{List of Tables}}%
  \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase{List of Figures}}%
  \renewcommand{\bibname}{\MakeUppercase{Bibliography}}%
}
%........................................


%****************************************
% EPIGRAPH

%%% Epigraph setup
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{.65\textwidth}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
%........................................


%%% PDF setup
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle    = {},
    pdfauthor   = {},
    pdfsubject  = {},
    pdfkeywords = {},
    colorlinks  = false,
    pdfborder   = {0 0 0},
    pdfpagemode = UseOutlines
}


%%% Utilities
\providecommand{\quotes}[1]{``#1''}
\providecommand{\singlequotes}[1]{`#1'}


%****************************************
% BEGIN
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}






\pagenumbering{Roman} 
\setcounter{page}{3} 

%****************************************
% ÖNSÖZ
\thispagestyle{plain}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ÖNSÖZ}
\doublespacing
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{0mm} % Top: 50mm
    {\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont \textbf{\MakeUppercase{Önsöz}}}\\
\end{center}

%%% Önsöz Metin
\par \lipsum[1-1]
\clearpage
%........................................


%%% Automatically generated.
%****************************************
% TABLE OF CONTENTS
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{İÇİNDEKİLER}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % dots for chapters
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\MakeUppercase\hfil\bfseries\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\mdseries}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\mdseries}
%\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER\space}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:}

\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{10mm} %İçindekiler yazısının üst tarafla boşluğunu ayarlar.
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{3\baselineskip} %İçindekiler yazısı ile boşluğu ayarlar.
%\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{7em} %Ana başlıkların girintisini ayarlıyor.
%\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}

%%% Spacing between items
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{\cftbeforechapskip}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{\cftbeforechapskip}

\begin{singlespace}
\tableofcontents
\end{singlespace}
\clearpage
%........................................

%****************************************
% TURKISH ABSTRACT
\thispagestyle{plain}
\selectlanguage{turkish}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ÖZET}
\doublespacing
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{13.5mm} % Top: 50mm
    {\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont \textbf{\MakeUppercase{Özet}}}\\
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
\end{center}

%%% Your Özet
\par \lipsum[1-1]

\noindent 
\clearpage
%........................................

\selectlanguage{english}

%****************************************
% ENGLISH SUMMARY
\thispagestyle{plain}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{SUMMARY}
\doublespacing
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{13mm} % Top: 50mm
    {\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont \textbf{\MakeUppercase{Abstract}}}\\
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
   abs\\

    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    January 2016
\end{center}

%%% Your Abstract
\par \lipsum[3-3]


\clearpage
%........................................

\selectlanguage{turkish}

%%% Automatically generated.
%****************************************
% LIST OF FIGURES
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ŞEKİLLER DİZİNİ}

%%% Spacing between items
\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
    \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
    {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
    \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
    \fi
    \chaptermark{#1}%
    \if@twocolumn
    \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
    \else
    \@makechapterhead{#2}%
    \@afterheading
    \fi}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\MakeUppercase\hfil\bfseries\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{.}

\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{20mm}
\setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{3\baselineskip}
\setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{\cftbeforechapskip}

\begin{singlespace}
\listoffigures
\end{singlespace}
\clearpage
%........................................

%%% Automatically generated.
%****************************************
% LIST OF TABLES
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLOLAR DİZİNİ}
\listoftables
\clearpage
%........................................

%%% Automatically generated.
%****************************************
% LIST OF TABLES
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{SEMBOLLER DİZİNİ}
\listoftables
\clearpage
%........................................

%%% If you need list of tables comment off below section.
%****************************************
% LIST OF TABLES
%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}
%\listoftables
%........................................

%****************************************
% BLANK PAGE
%\clearpage
%\afterpage{\null\newpage}
%\clearpage
%........................................


%****************************************
% DEDICATION
%\newenvironment{dedication}
%  {\clearpage           % we want a new page
%   \thispagestyle{empty}% no header and footer
%   \vspace*{2in}       % some space at the top 
%   \centering
%  }
%  {\par                    % end the paragraph
%   \vfill
%   \clearpage           % finish off the page
%  }

%\begin{dedication}
%To my family and for those who embrace trash
%\end{dedication}
%........................................

%****************************************
% ACKNOWLEDGMENTS teşekkürler
\thispagestyle{plain}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TEŞEKKÜRLER}
\doublespacing
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{13mm} % Top: 50mm
    {\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont \textbf{\MakeUppercase{TEŞEKKÜRLER}}}\\
    \vspace{3\baselineskip}
\end{center}

%%% Your Ack.
\par \lipsum[1-1]

\clearpage
%........................................


\pagenumbering{arabic}


%****************************************
% CHAPTERS
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\include{chapter4}
\include{chapter5}
%........................................


%%% Automatically generated.
%****************************************
% BIBLIOGRAPHY (Kaynaklar)
\nocite{*} % Add all references
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{KAYNAKLAR}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\begin{singlespace}
\setlength{\bibsep}{2\itemsep}
\bibliography{literature}
\end{singlespace}
\clearpage
%........................................


%****************************************
% APPENDICES (Ekler)
\appendix
\phantomsection

%%% Below code is used for multiple appendices, for single appendix you need to remove code between appendices comment.
%%% remove start. [appendices]
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}} 
\chapter*{APPENDICES}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}{EKLER}{}{}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}} 
%%% remove end. [appendices]

\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section}
\makeatother

\include{appendix_materials}
\include{appendix_project}
%........................................


\end{document}
```

Comment: it is really hard to debug a screenshot, please make a small document that shows the problem and add it as code text (the `{}` button) to your question

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, and the relevant `inputenc` (preferably `utf8`)?

Comment: @Bernard the image suggests both those were used (but the file may be mis-encoded of course)

Comment: Hi David, i edited the post

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I was unable to read the screenshot, so I mentioned the two main reasons for this inconvenience…

Comment: you have added some code, but the code posted does not produce the error, please complete a small example document so people can run it and debug the error.

Comment: possibly you just need to add `\begin{document} \chapter{something}\end{document}`   or whatever is the minimum you need to generate the problem that you are asking about.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i edited the post. Can you look again?

Comment: Please make this a minimal example that others can copy an test as is. Those included files are not accessible to us. Plus `hyperref` should be loaded last. Please make the MWE as small as possible and only containing the parts that are relevant for your problem.

Comment: No the example still can not be run you have `\include.... for all kinds of files that no one other than you has, please  try and do what you ask others to do, copy what you have posted to a new directory and try to run it. As it happens egreg could spot the error but posting examples like this makes it harder for people to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `\uppercase` in `\MakeUppercase` in the redefinition of `\chapter`:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\centering\bfseries}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\  \thechapter}
  {2\baselineskip}
  {\MakeUppercase} % <---- you had \uppercase
```

Beware that `hyperref` should be loaded *last*. You may want to load it also with the option `unicode`.